# iOS dismiss UIAlertView beforing showing another

Tags: ios, uialertview, dismiss

I have a Utils class which shows UIAlertView when certain notifications are triggered. Is there a way to dismiss any open UIAlertViews before showing a new one?

Currenty I am doing this when the app enters the background using

```
[self checkViews:application.windows];
```

on applicationDidEnterBackground

```
- (void)checkViews:(NSArray *)subviews {
    Class AVClass = [UIAlertView class];
    Class ASClass = [UIActionSheet class];
    for (UIView * subview in subviews){
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:AVClass]){
            [(UIAlertView *)subview dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)subview cancelButtonIndex] animated:NO];
        } else if ([subview isKindOfClass:ASClass]){
            [(UIActionSheet *)subview dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIActionSheet *)subview cancelButtonIndex] animated:NO];
        } else {
            [self checkViews:subview.subviews];
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it easy on applicationDidEnterBackground as I can use application.windows

Can I use the AppDelegate or anything similar to get all the views, loop through them and dismiss any UIAlertViews?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
  NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
  if ([subviews count] > 0)
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
      [(UIAlertView *)[subviews objectAtIndex:0] dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)[subviews objectAtIndex:0] cancelButtonIndex] animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: …and that's why iterating private internal view structures is a fragile process.

Comment: sorry, i have used the same code, but it is not working for me.

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS 7 anymore. Alertview is added to _UIModalItemHostingWindow, and there is no reference to it.

Comment: does anyone know how to achieve above task in ios 8 or above.

Answer (score 27):

iOS6 compatible version:

```
for (UIWindow* w in UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows)
    for (NSObject* o in w.subviews)
        if ([o isKindOfClass:UIAlertView.class])
            [(UIAlertView*)o dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView*)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Have you found an alternative for iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

iOS7 compatible version:

I made a category interface that stores all instance in init method.

I know it's a very inefficient way.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@interface UIAlertView(EnumView)

+ (void)startInstanceMonitor;
+ (void)stopInstanceMonitor;
+ (void)dismissAll;
@end

@implementation UIAlertView(EnumView)
static BOOL _isInstanceMonitorStarted = NO;

+ (NSMutableArray *)instances
{
    static NSMutableArray *array = nil;
    if (array == nil)
        array = [NSMutableArray array];

    return array;
}


- (void)_newInit
{
    [[UIAlertView instances] addObject:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self]];
    [self _oldInit];
}

- (void)_oldInit
{
    // dummy method for storing original init IMP.
}

- (void)_newDealloc
{
    [[UIAlertView instances] removeObject:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self]];
    [self _oldDealloc];

}
- (void)_oldDealloc
{
    // dummy method for storing original dealloc IMP.
}

static void replaceMethod(Class c, SEL old, SEL new)
{
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, new);
    class_replaceMethod(c, old, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod));
}

+ (void)startInstanceMonitor
{
    if (!_isInstanceMonitorStarted) {
        _isInstanceMonitorStarted = YES;
        replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, @selector(_oldInit), @selector(init));
        replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, @selector(init), @selector(_newInit));

        replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, @selector(_oldDealloc), NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"));
        replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"), @selector(_newDealloc));
    }
}

+ (void)stopInstanceMonitor
{
    if (_isInstanceMonitorStarted) {
        _isInstanceMonitorStarted = NO;
        replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, @selector(init), @selector(_oldInit));
        replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"), @selector(_oldDealloc));
    }
}

+ (void)dismissAll
{
    for (NSValue *value in [UIAlertView instances]) {
        UIAlertView *view = [value nonretainedObjectValue];

        if ([view isVisible]) {
            [view dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:view.cancelButtonIndex animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Start instance monitoring before using UIAlertView.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   //...  
   //...

    [UIAlertView startInstanceMonitor];

    return YES;
}
```

Call dismissAll before showing another.

```
[UIAlertView dismissAll];
```

It's better using a singleton pattern if you can control all UIAlertViews.

But in my case, I need this code for closing javascript alert dialog in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS8 in favor of `UIAlertController` (which is a `UIViewController`, presented modally), you can't preset 2 alerts at the same time (from the same viewController at least). The second alert will simply not be presented.

I wanted to partially emulate `UIAlertView`'s behavior, as well as prevent showing multiple alerts at once. Bellow is my solution, which uses window's `rootViewController` for presenting alerts (usually, that is appDelegate's navigation controller). I declared this in AppDelegate, but you can put it where you desire.

If you encounter any sorts of problems using it, please report here in comments.

```
@interface UIViewController (UIAlertController)

// these are made class methods, just for shorter semantics. In reality, alertControllers
// will be presented by window's rootViewController (appdelegate.navigationController)
+ (UIAlertController *)presentAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                     message:(NSString *)message
                           cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
                           otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles
                                     handler:(void (^)(NSInteger buttonIndex))block;
+ (UIAlertController *)presentAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                     message:(NSString *)message
                           cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (UIAlertController)

+ (UIAlertController *)presentAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                     message:(NSString *)message
                           cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
{
    return [self presentAlertWithTitle:title message:message cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                     otherButtonTitles:nil handler:nil];
}
+ (UIAlertController *)presentAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                     message:(NSString *)message
                           cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
                           otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles
                                     handler:(void (^)(NSInteger buttonIndex))block
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        if (block)
            block(0);
    }];
    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    [otherButtonTitles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *title, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            if (block)
                block(idx + 1); // 0 is cancel
        }];
        [alert addAction:action];
    }];

    id<UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
    if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        [rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            [rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    } else {
        [rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    return alert;
}

@end
```