# Dismiss alertview from the entire app

Tags: xcode, uialertview

When a user clicks on a button, I'm calling a webservice and the parsing is done from another class. Meanwhile, while I'm getting the data, I'm showing an alertview with activity indicator to tell user to wait. The alertview dismisses only after I get the response.  If  there is any sort of Error/failure, it shows an alert that says "Failure" and a cancel button "Ok". But the alertview with activity indicator continues to show and thus freezes the app. How do I dismiss this from the class where I'm calling & parsing the webservice?

Comment: If all go well than how u dismis alertview with activity indicator?

Comment: If all goes well, I have an observer for notification that is posted in parserDidEndDocument. The function that calls when this notification is observed dismisses the alertview with activity indicator using dissmissAlertview: . But what if there is an error?

Comment: I have loads of classes and if there is anyway I could use one function to detect alertview and dismiss throughout the app that would be better I'm guessing

Comment: use same code to dissmiss on click of "OK" button of failure alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dismiss all the existing alert views already displayed in the app by using the code shared at:

[iOS dismiss UIAlertView beforing showing another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399219/ios-dismiss-uialertview-beforing-showing-another)

```
for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
    for (NSObject* o in w.subviews)
        if ([o isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
            [(UIAlertView*)o dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView*)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
```